# Wrong password in git pull - re-prompt password?

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I've set a password for my private keys which I use on my project and when I did:

```
git pull
```

`git` prompted me for a password and I accidentally typed in the wrong password with +1 more unneeded character, and when I retried to `git pull` again, CLI said:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I **re-prompt** `git pull` so I will ask me for the password again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following command,

```
git credential-cache exit
```

And if you want to reduce the remember password time-out, use this,

```
git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout=3600" //in milli seconds
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github) link for more details..